# opening a PDF file on desktop in Chrome instead of Edge

Tags: pdf

What do I need to do to have my Windows 10 computer open up PDF's in Chrome instead of Edge?  Chrome is already set as my default browser.

Comment: Use "Open With" on any PDF file and change the default PDF application

Answer (score 1):

Open Windows settings, then go to System and Standard APPS. At the bottom there should be something like Chose standard app by file type, click that. Then scroll down to PDF, all file types are shown on the left. When you find PDF, click on the current Edge and chose Chrome instead.